# JQuery on click causes page reload and hover does not change CSS

Tags: jquery

Doing some JQuery testing - Clicking Page 1 sends an ID through Ajax to retrieve new data, then populates/replaces content in id="replace" line.  Likewise for Page 2, Page 3, except different content is retrieved.  Few issues:

1. Does not work with `$("abc p").on("click", function()`, but does work with `$("p").on("click", function()`, but with the latter, each time I click I get the correct update, but the page refreshes all the time.  Would like to prevent page refresh and just do the replace.
2. Would like the Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 to get an underline when mouse hovers over it, but does not work with `$('#abc p').hover().css('text-decoration','underline');`.
3. Thought `$("abc p")` is the way to select all the

   within id="abc", but seems like there is a problem in this implementation.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="abc">TEST PAGE</div>
    <p style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;" id="91">Page 1</p>
    <p style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;" id="75">Page 2</p>
    <p style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;" id="88">Page 3<p>
  </div>
  <p id="replace">Replace this Text</p>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("abc p").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('p').hover().css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'testAjax2.php',
          data: {
            "articleID": id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#replace").html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Typo. `$('abc p')` needs to be `$('#abc p')`. Also, nothing about any of that logic should cause a page change. 2) Your hover logic is completely incorrect. See http://api.jquery.com/hover. Also, use CSS for UI decoration, not JS. 3) See #1. I'd strongly suggest you read the getting started with jQuery guide as you have some fundamental errors: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: Also, `<p>` needs to be `</p>` after 'Page 3'

Answer (score 0):

Took Rory's advice above.  Here is the updated code that works.  The page reloads that seemed to be happening were actually unintended HTML page include files from the testAjax2.php page (may not have been a reload, but looked that way).  Didn't realize that whatever is on the page comes across into the data variable in the Ajax call. Changed that page to only contain php/mysql data retrieval processing and the data replacement works seamlessly now.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .link:hover {text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; color:blue;}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="abc">
        <p class="link" id="91">Page 1</p>
        <p class="link" id="75">Page 2</p>
        <p class="link" id="88">Page 3</p>
    </div>
    <span id="replace">Replace this Text</span>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#abc p").click(function(){
           var id = ($(this)[0].id);
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'testAjax2.php',
               data: {"articleID":id},
               success: function(data){
                   $("#replace").html(data);
               }
            });
        });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var id = ($(this)[0].id);`  Can someone explain the purpose of `[0]` ?  Script does not seem to work without it.